# How to get word count from TF*IDF value in sklearn

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I want to get the count of a word in a given sentence using only tf*idf matrix of a set of sentences. I use TfidfVectorizer from sklearn.feature_extraction.text.

Example :

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

sentences = ("The sun is shiny i like the sun","I have been exposed to sun")
vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words="english",lowercase=False)
tfidf_matrix = vect.fit_transform(sentences).toarray()
```

I want to be able to calculate the number of times the term "sun" occurs in the first sentence (which is 2) using only tfidf_matrix[0] and probably vect.idf_ .
I know there are infinite ways to get term frequency and words count but I have a special case where I only have a tf*idf matrix.
I already tried to divide the tf*idf value of the word "sun" in the first sentence by its idf value to get tf. Then I multiplied tf by the total number of words in the sentence to get the words count. Unfortunately, I get wrong values.

Comment: Are you able to fit another tfidf matrix? There is an option `use_idf` that you can set to `False`.

Comment: Actually, I can't. But, let's presume that I can. Setting `use_idf`  to `False` will allow me to have the term frequencies (which I already can get by dividing the tf*idf value by the idf value). How would I calculate the word count from the term frequency value?

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that I mis-understood the prompt. Are you also normalizing the term vectors?

Comment: No problem.. Yes, the default norm value is set to "l2"so yes term vectors are normalized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intuitive thing to do would be exactly what you tried: multiply each *tf* value by the number of words in the sentence you're examining. However, I think the key observation here is that each row has been normalized by its euclidean length. So multiplying each row by the number of words in that sentence is at best *approximating* the denormalized row, which is why you get weird values. AFAIK, you can't denormalize the tf*idf matrix without knowing the norms of each of the original rows ahead of time. This is primarily because there are an infinite number of vectors that can be mapped to any one normalized vector. So without the norms, you can't retrieve the correct magnitude of the original vector. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912479/denormalize-vector) for more details about what I mean.

That being said, I think there's a workaround in our case. We can at least retrieve the normalized ratios of the term counts in each sentence, i.e., sun appears twice as much as shiny. I found that normalizing each row so that the sum of the tf values is 1 and *then* multiplying those values by the length of the *stopword-filtered* sentences seems to retrieve the original word counts.

To demonstrate:

```
sentences = ("The sun is shiny i like the sun","I have been exposed to sun")
vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words="english",lowercase=False)
mat = vect.fit_transform(sentences).toarray()
q = mat / vect.idf_
sums = np.ones((q.shape[0], 1))
lens = np.ones((q.shape[0], 1))
for ix in xrange(q.shape[0]):
    sums[ix] = np.sum(q[ix,:])
    lens[ix] = len([x for x in sentences[ix].split() if unicode(x) in vect.get_feature_names()]) #have to filter out stopwords
sum_to_1 = q / sums
tf = sum_to_1 * lens
print tf
```

yields:

```
[[ 1.  0.  1.  1.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

I tried this with a few more complicated sentences and it seems to work alright. Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for the explication and the code.